# digit regex no match

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, ubuntu

I keep getting an error that I shouldn't be getting and I am no regex expert but it should be so simple. I looked over it so many times and can't figure out why it isn't working. I have also searched a bunch for something similar but I can't find anyone that has the same problem.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
    at DailyData.importUsers(DailyData.java:456)
    at DailyData.main(DailyData.java:40)
```

Here is my code, through debugging I found its the last line that gives the error:

```
Pattern memberSincePattern = Pattern.compile("\\W*(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\\W*(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
Matcher memberSinceMatcher = memberSincePattern.matcher("12:12:12 12/12/2012");
String msGroupOne = memberSinceMatcher.group(1);
```

I am using eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I have imported the proper libraries and have tried \d{1,2} for the digits as well as getting rid of the leading \W*. I want it to be able to grab either 1 or two digits for each group.
I get no syntax errors or warnings on this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception indicates, you need to find a **match** to your **regex** before looking for a matched group.

For example, you could use `Matcher#matches`, as follows:

```
Pattern memberSincePattern = Pattern.compile("\\W*(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\\W*(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
Matcher memberSinceMatcher = memberSincePattern.matcher("12:12:12 12/12/2012");

if(memberSinceMatcher.matches()) {
    String msGroupOne = memberSinceMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Here's the [javadoc entry for `Matcher#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()).

---

As a side note, I'd like to point out that if you want to match only a sub-sequence of your original `String`, at least one time, you should use `Matcher#find` instead of `Matcher#matches`. Possibly in a `while` loop :)

Comment: Ah yes, I can't believe I forgot that! I have been using matcher.find() and forgot it here. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisLang You might want to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you got your response, so the quality of this website remains great :)

Comment: Will do, it says I can do so in 1 minute. Ya I am just a cs student but I have found this website and the people on it very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! Thank you. Enjoy the community ;)